ERROR: tf-keras 2.15.1 requires tensorflow<2.16,>=2.15, but you have tensorflow 2.16.1 which is incompatible
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
tf-keras 2.15.1 requires tensorflow<2.16,>=2.15, but you have tensorflow 2.16.1 which is incompatible.
How to solve this issue, I'm getting this error in Google Colab
